# Magento2 how to connect to elasticsearch

Tags: catalogsearch

I have 2 servers, 1 server installed with `nginx+php+mysql+Magento2.4.2`.

Another elasticsearch 7.13.4 was installed on the server.

I want to connect the magento2 search engine to the elastic search server. How to configure my elasticsearch server,

Does anyone know? Please tell me how to configure it.
Thank you very much

Comment: elasticsearch.yml how to set

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Magento admin panel **Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search**
change **Elasticsearch Server Hostname** value to your Elasticsearch server IP Address as shown in below image:

[image]

Click on **Test Connection** if shown **Successfull** on **Test Connection** button than good to go.

Comment: My magento server ip is 123.45.32.67, and I put my Elasticsearch server hostname in 123.45.32.66, but the connection failed. easticsearch is installed on my elasticsearch server. Is there anything else you need to configure?

Comment: I'm not sure what this document says： https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/search-engine/configure-nginx.html?lang=en

Comment: It means that your ElasticSearch installation is not completed or something wrong. You can follow this guide [https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configuring-elasticsearch-magento/](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configuring-elasticsearch-magento/) for step by step ElasticSearch installation. For production usage and if you don't want to worry such problem, I highly recommend [https://www.cloudways.com/](https://www.cloudways.com/) that I been using over 4 years seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

> **Please Run below command**

```
    php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento config:set  catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname  192.168.1.1 (HOSTNAME OR IP ADDRESS)

    php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_index_prefix  magento2_index (INDEX NAME)

    php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_enable_auth 1 (MUST BE ONE FOR ENABLE)

    php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_username  elastic_user (YOUR USER NAME)

    php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_password  elastic_password (YOUR PASSWORD)
```

Checked in admin : https://prnt.sc/P2W98B8_YU_B

**Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using this the command line.

```
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname localhost
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port 9200
```